# Understanding Java References in Java collections

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I am having trouble understanding some simple code relating with Lists and maps. Take the code below as an example:

```
public class test {

private Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap ;

public test(){
    myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
}

public void addToMap(String ss){

    List<String> myTemp = myMap.get(ss);
    Random  r = new Random();
    if(myTemp == null){

        myTemp = new ArrayList<String>();
        myMap.put(r.nextInt(100), myTemp);
    }

    myTemp.add(ss);

}

public Map<Integer, List<String>> getMap1(){
    return myMap;
}


public  static void main(String args[]){

    test myTest = new test();
    myTest.addToMap("abdc");
    myTest.addToMap("eeer");
    System.out.println(myTest.getMap1());

}

}
```

How exactly does the `addToMap()` add a new element to the mylist Map. More specifically, how does `myTemp.add(ss)` add a new element to `myMap` when `myTemp` is a local variable and gets deleted once its done executing. Moreover, removing `myTemp.add(ss)` from the `addToMap()` method prints out an empty HashMap in the main method, why is this? How does the put method insert the element into the map when it is executed before the add method? Thanks.

Edit: I edited the code to make a little more sense.

Comment: This code is candidate for refactoring and code review...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C++, in Java all variables are **references** to the real objects. So, when you do

```
myTemp = new Object();
```

you create an object in the heap whose reference is copied to the stack variable myTemp. If the reference is added to the list (or other variable), a copy of the reference is added there.

Once myTemp is destroyed, the object continues alive. The exception is when all the references to the object are gone; then the object can not be reached by the code and Garbage Collection can (but it is not forced to) delete it from memory.

Answer (score 2):

`myTemp` isn't the thing - the list - it is instead a reference to the thing.  But it isn't that specific reference which you are putting into the map; it is the thing to which it refers.  The map has its own reference to the thing, so deleting the `myTemp` reference doesn't affect the map.

Answer (score 1):

myTemp is a **reference** to the list. The list is allocated in heap memory and myTemp is actually is a pointer stored on the stack. Whenever you exit the function it gets deleted but the memory allocated in heap memory won't get deleted. Memories allocated in heap memory release when there is no reference to them by **Garbage Collector**.

You are right. When you leave the addToMap() method, the myTemp will be released(Actually it will be poped from the stack) but the list which is allocated in heap memory space will remain. Everything which is created using **new** keyword, will be placed inside heap memory space.

Read this link [Java Reference Objects](http://www.kdgregory.com/index.php?page=java.refobj)

Answer (score 1):

From a best practice point of view, calling a HashMap "mylist" is problematic in a number of ways. It isn't orthogonal and "mylist" doesn't tell you a lot about its usage.

In answer to your question, it's a simple case of, if the item exists in the map, it is retrieved and the string added to it, if not the list is created and added to the map. As long as the map is in scope, the references to any lists added to it (even if they were created in the scope of a function) remain in scope themselves.

However, this isn't a helpful example at all as it mixes its naming and provides no real world use-case.